# Forward or backward sequential feature selection?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, matlab, stepwise-regression

I was trying to carry out feature selection on a dataset using sequential feature selection. The dataset contains more than 5000 observations (rows) and 22 features (columns). Now I see that there are two options to do it. One is 'backward' and the other is 'forward'. I was reading the article ['*An Introduction to Variable and Feature Selection*'](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf) and it is mentioned that both these techniques yield nested subsets of variables.

When I try to do forward selection using the below code:

```
%% sequentialfs (forward) and knn
rng(100)
c = cvpartition(groups_cv,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter');
fun = @(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(fitcknn(xtrain,ytrain,'NumNeighbors',5),xtest));
[fs,history]  = sequentialfs(fun,data_cv_nor,groups_cv,'cv',c,'options',opts, 'direction', 'forward');
```

I get the following set of features.

> Final columns included:  8 9 11 12 14 17 19

And when I try to do backward selection using the below code:

```
%% sequentialfs (backward) and knn
rng(100)
c = cvpartition(groups_cv,'k',10);
opts = statset('display','iter');
fun = @(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest) sum(ytest ~= predict(fitcknn(xtrain,ytrain,'NumNeighbors',5),xtest));
[fs,history]  = sequentialfs(fun,data_cv_nor,groups_cv,'cv',c,'options',opts, 'direction', 'backward');
```

I get the following set of features.

> Final columns included:  2 3 6 7 8 11 12 14 16 17 18 19 21 22

Clearly, backward technique has selected more number of features, and both these techniques share less number of common elements.

My questions are:

1. Among these two techniques which one is preferable? How do I choose?
2. If I change the seed, then it gives me a different set of features. How do I go about this? Is something like 100 times 10-fold cross validation preferable in this case, i.e., running the same code 100 times with different seeds and observing the most frequent feature?

The above question is based on one of the reviewer comments for my research article which mentions

"*The major limitation I see is that authors did not try any of the state-of-the-art feature engineering algorithms for the selection of variables, prior to the application of the four selected algorithms (LR, RF, BoostTree, SVM). While they did a statistical testing of the features, I think that being able to have similar performances with many less variables could be specially interesting in this setting. Most of the classifier-oriented research do this type of preprocessing and compare the runs with all variables and some subsets of variables as selected by different algorithms. For matlab authors can have a initial look at:
https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/feature-selection.html*"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The facts that you are getting different answers from forward and backward selection, and that you get different answers when you change the seed, should give you pause.  Clearly, these can't all be right.  Most likely, none of them are.  The simplest answer is that you should not use these methods at all.  Here are some threads you might want to read:

- [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290)
- [Why are p-values misleading after performing a stepwise selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179945/)
- [Backward selection for Cox model using R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/115850/)

In place of these methods, you might stop and ask why you need to select variables at all.  Twenty-two variables with 5,000 data should present no real problems for most things.  You could also read this:

- [What are modern, easily used alternatives to stepwise regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13686/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I wanted to try the feature selection method based on the reviewer comments for a research article. Please see the modified question to see the comment. The reviewer had suggested to do feature selection. I guess now i can use the above references for response.

Comment: @prashanth, I would need to know a lot more about your project, but their recommendation sounds mindless. (Not that I'm skeptical--I see that plenty.)  For your case (p=22, k=5000), there is little need for feature selection for anything. If you want to appease the reviewers, something like regularization or PCA (both listed on the MATLAB documentation page they linked to) would be more defensible.

Comment: @gung Agree about backward/forward selection not being needed. But OP could try (or could have tried) low variance filtering and correlation filtering of features.